# device deployment in iOS without connecting the device manually

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4.3

I am working in iOS native applications using Xcode in objective C with SUP 2.1.3 as backend.I have deployed my application in iPAD by connecting it to mac machine.Now I would like to know, if I can deploy my application into iPAD without connecting the iPAD to mac machine ie by transferring any files to the iPAD.? Or is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Currently, there is no supported way of doing this

There used to be, in an early version of Xcode 4. Then Apple killed it - for reasons of being too buggy.

I, like you, often wish they would bring it back, just so that those that do use it don't have to use cables all the time.

### Except for Ad Hoc

EDIT: I now understand the question better - you don't want to use the iPad for development as in debugger and whatnot. You want your friend to be able to run your apple on his device. Got it. **Google `iOS ad hoc`**

Comment: Thank you Erway..I think it was using ipa files.Shall I get more information regarding that.? if you dont mind

Comment: Ah. Yes, you *could* export your app as an ipa - with correct signing - import it to iTunes, then do a wireless sync to the iPad - but forget about any serious development this way. Too many steps, and no debugger.

Comment: so you are saying like now also I can do it without conneting to mac machine?sorry i didnt get you...the scenario is I have a friend with an iPAD.He doesnt have a mac machine with him.So if I register his iPAD's UDID with my devloper certificate, can I run my application in his iPAD by any means,ie by transfering ipa file or something like that ?

Comment: Now I understand - you don't want to use the iPad for development as in debugger and whatnot. You want your friend to be able to run your apple on his device. Got it. **Google `iOS ad hoc`**

Comment: Thank you Erway...I am trying to learn more about this.Eventhough,till now, I havent got a clear idea about this.I am very much new to this technology.Thanks for your valuable answers.